# Scene Kit Animation

Tags: macos, scenekit

Anyone have any idea why I can't get this simple animation to work?  It just doesn't play.

```
self.scene = [SCNScene scene];

SCNNode *sun = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:[SCNSphere sphereWithRadius:5.0]];
SCNNode *moon = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:[SCNSphere sphereWithRadius:2.0]];

moon.position = SCNVector3Make(7.0, 7.0, 7.0);
moon.pivot = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-7.0, -7.0, -7.0);

CABasicAnimation *startAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"rotation"];
startAnim.duration = 5;
startAnim.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT;
startAnim.toValue =[NSValue valueWithSCNVector4:SCNVector4Make(0.0, 0.0, 0.0,1.0)];
startAnim.timingFunction =[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

[moon addAnimation:startAnim forKey:@"rotate"];
[sun addChildNode:moon];
[[self.scene rootNode] addChildNode:sun];
```

I think the problem is...

```
 startAnim.toValue =[NSValue valueWithSCNVector4:SCNVector4Make(0.0, 0.0, 0.0,1.0)];
```

Cheers

Comment: Have you called play on your SCNView, or set it to play automatically in the xib?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed SCNVector4Make(0.0, 0.0, 0.0,1.0) is not a valid rotation.
"rotation" is an axis angle made with 4 floats {x y z w}.
the 3 first floats x y z represents the axis, w is the rotation in radian.
So (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) is not a valid axis (or in the best case it represents a null rotation)

Comment: Thanks, Though if I have use any figures for the axis and rotation, it still doesn't animate.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get your example working with the "rotation" keypath either, but I could using "transform". For example:

```
CABasicAnimation *startAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
startAnim.duration = 5;
startAnim.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT;
startAnim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(3.14, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)];
startAnim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
[moon addAnimation:startAnim forKey:@"transform"];
```